# Excel VBA Using 'Application.AutomationSecurity' to prevent macro running in a new file created by macro from template

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel project reporting system which uses Excel VBA. The report files are created on a monthly basis, i.e one file for January, one for February etc. At the end of each month I use a macro in Book 1 to open a template file and then carry forward summary data from the current month into the new month's report file(Book 2).

At the end of the Book 1 macro routine it resets the date, on one of the Book 2 worksheets(to the 1st of the month) and herein lies my problem, the cell, into which this date is entered, is linked to a Book 2 macro that runs when this date changes.

By using 'Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable' at the start of the Book 1 macro I have managed to stop the Book 2 macro running, so far so good.

After resetting the date I use 'Application.AutomationSecurity = PreviousSecurity', where Previous Security is a variable containing the initial state of the AutomationSecurity before it was disabled.

The macro concludes with no problem and brings the Book 2 file to the foreground, at this point the user needs to manually run a Book 2 macro, to update a logo, but even though I have reset the Automation Security I cannot run macros in Book 2 until the file has been closed and re-opened.

The relevant bits of the Book 1 macro are:

```
Sub NewCarryFwd3()

    Dim Folder As String, CFileName As String
' The 'NewClient' and 'NewProject' variables are defined as Public at head of module

' Get file names

    Folder = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    CFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

' Stop Excel screen updating

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Stop autocalculation of formulae to speed up procedure

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
'**********
'Prevent Macros in the new Template running

    Dim previousSecurity As MsoAutomationSecurity
    PreviousSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    

'**********
' Calculate new DRS month dates

    Dim OldDate As Date, NewDate As Date, NewMonth As String

    OldDate = Workbooks(CFileName).Sheets("Setup").Range("Month_start").Value
    NewDate = DateAdd("m", 1, OldDate)
    NewMonth = Choose(Month(NewDate), "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

' Open New DRS File from Microsoft user's template folder

    Dim NextDRS As String

    Workbooks.Add template:= _
        "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Oasis 3D DRS_V3.xltm"
    
    NextDRS = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'******************************************************************************

**' My Code to update the summary data goes in here - too much to include!**

**' After updating Summary data the macro ends as below**

'******************************************************************************


' Set initial Weekly date to first day of new month?
' Set first weekly data

    Workbooks(NextDRS).Sheets("Weekly").Range("WkDay7").Value = NewDate
    
    Sheets("Weekly").Protect Sheets("Weekly").Protect
    
' Allow macros in New workbook to run

    Application.AutomationSecurity = PreviousSecurity
    
' Create New file Name

    Dim NewFilename As String
    
    NewFilename = Folder & "\DRS " & Workbooks(CFileName).Sheets("Setup").Range("C2").Text & " " & NewMonth & ".xlsm"
    Workbooks(NextDRS).Activate
    Sheets("Daily Report").Select

' Check if new file name already exists if so add numeric ID

    Dim f As Long
    
    f = 1
    Do While Dir(NewFilename) <> ""
        NewFilename = Folder & "\DRS " & Workbooks(CFileName).Sheets("Setup").Range("C2").Text & " " & NewMonth & " " & f & ".xlsm"
        f = f + 1
    Loop

'**********
' Save new workbook for next month in Excel 2007 xlsm format.

    Workbooks(NextDRS).SaveAs FileName:= _
        NewFilename _
        , FileFormat:=52, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=True

' Re-activate screen updating & autocalculation

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Is their some way to reenable the AutomationSecurity so that the Book 2 macros can be run without having to close and reopen the file?

Comment: Perhaps use `Application.EnableEvents = False` instead of `AutomationSecurity`

Comment: Thanks Chris, just the job. For some reason I didn’t think this would work on the second workbook,

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the workbook you opened/added, reset the AutomationSecurity property to the previous value, and then reopen your workbook.

I think you might have misunderstood the scope of the AutomationSecurity property.  From the Object Reference:

```
"Returns or sets an MsoAutomationSecurity constant that represents the security mode that Microsoft Excel uses when programmatically opening files."
```

In other words, this property only affects how workbooks are opened.  It doesn't change the behavior of workbooks that are already open.

I think your solution is to just:

1. Programmatically close the workbook after you update the summary data,
2. Set the AutomationSecurity property back to the previous state, and then
3. Programmatically re-open the workbook.

Everything should be fine after that and the user probably won't even know something changed.