# VBA quits after worksheet copy

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to
Loop through all excel files in a folder "\xxxx\INPUT\File1.xlsm".
Copy a particular sheet "Template".
Paste the "Template" sheet into another file "\xxxx\TEMPLATE\WEBADI.xlsm".
Rename file WEBADI.xlsm as File1_WEBADI and save it in folder "\xxxx\OUTPUT\File1_WEBADI.xlsm

Below is the VBA code I worked on.
It executes fine until the step where it copies the sheet "Template" to the WEBADI.xlsm
Once the sheet is copied the VBA code exits execution without any error.

```
Sub CpyRebateADI()
 
 
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim OutputPath As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
 
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook, wb3 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    

    myPath = "\\XXXX\INPUT\"
    OutputPath = "\\XXXX\OUTPUT\"
    
    If Right(myPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        myPath = myPath & "\"
    End If
 
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    previousSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 

    myExtension = "*.xl*"

    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
 

    Do While myFile <> ""

             
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        Debug.Print (myFile)
        
        filestr1 = "\\XXXX\TEMPLATE\WEBADI.xlsm"
        Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(filestr1, UpdateLinks:=False)
        Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile, UpdateLinks:=False)
        
        
        Dim source_worksheet As Worksheet
        Set source_worksheet = Wb2.Worksheets("Template")
        source_worksheet.Visible = True

        
        Dim target_worksheet As Worksheet
        Set target_worksheet = wb3.Worksheets("WebADI")

            
        source_worksheet.Copy After:=target_worksheet
        'This is where the macro stops executing
                
        wb3.SaveAs filename:=OutputPath & myFile & "_WebADI", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        
        Wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
        

        myFile = Dir
    Loop


    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.AutomationSecurity = previousSecurity
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Comment: The reason is the line `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable`. You have to use  another setting.

Comment: Similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63572097/excel-vba-using-application-automationsecurity-to-prevent-macro-running-in-a-n

Comment: I removed Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable, it still exits macro execution after copying worksheet.

Comment: Sorry, code is working for me with my example data and `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI`. If you left it at `Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable` the code will not work. `Application.AutomationSecurity ` is an `Application` wide  setting and will stay at the value you set last.

Comment: @Storax Thanks a ton! I have set it to Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI and now it works fine